Marginal structural model using PROC PHREG
I would like to fit a marginal structural model to account for treatment switching during follow-up.
I found a great paper on how to do this in R: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0010482519302082
But, of course, I am working in clinical trials and using SAS.
In 2000, Hernan, Brumback, and Robins provide code for constructing MSMs in SAS:
https://journals.lww.com/epidem/fulltext/2000/09000/marginal_structural_models_to_estimate_the_causal.12.aspx
Because PROC PHREG did not support time-updated weights, pooled logistic regression is used to obtain the marginal hazard ratio.
Now that it is 2024, and not 2000, I was wondering whether or not time-updated weights could now be incorporated into PROC PHREG, or is pooled logistic regression still the de facto MSM fitting approach?? Alternatively, are there well-known macros I can use to fit this model?

This question seems too SAS-specific to be on-topic on this site and thus may soon be closed here. If you are forced to use SAS then you will probably get a better response from an SAS-specific help site. Or see if you can do some data pre-processing following the tutorial in the first paper and then do the final analysis if possible in SAS. Or show that you can do it in R and discuss with your supervisors why that isn't allowed.
